# Is A==0 really better than ~A?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, benchmarking, logical-operators

**Introduction to problem setup**

I was doing some benchmarks involving - `~A` and `A==0`for a `double array with no NaNs`, both of which convert `A` to a logical array where all `zeros` are converted to `true` values and rest are set as `false` values.

For the benchmarking, I have used three sets of input data –

- Very small to small sized data - `15:5:100`
- Small to medium sized data - `50:40:1000`
- Medium to large sized data - `200:400:3800`

The input is created with `A = round(rand(N)*20)`, where N is the parameter taken from the size array. Thus, `N` would vary from `15 to 100 with stepsize of 5` for the first set and similarly for the second and third sets. Please note that I am defining datasize as N, thus the number of elements would be datasize^2 or N^2.

**Benchmarking Code**

```
N_arr = 15:5:100; %// for very small to small sized input array
N_arr = 50:40:1000; %// for small to medium sized input array
N_arr = 200:400:3800; %// for medium to large sized input array
timeall = zeros(2,numel(N_arr));
for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)
    A = round(rand(N_arr(k1))*20);

    f = @() ~A;
    timeall(1,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() A==0;
    timeall(2,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
end
```

**Results**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Finally the questions**

One can see how `A==0` performs better than `~A` across all datasizes. So here are some observations and related questions alongside them –

1. `A==0` has one relational operator and one operand, whereas `~A` has only one relational operator. Both produce logical arrays and both accept double arrays. In fact, `A==0` would work with `NaNs` too, wheras `~A` won’t. So, why is still `~A` at least not as good as `A==0` as it looks like `A==0` is doing more work or am I missing something here?
2. There’s a peculiar drop of elapsed time with `A==0` and thus increased performance at `N = 320`, i.e. at `102400` elements for A. I have observed this across many runs with that size on two different systems that I have access to. So what’s going on there?

Comment: In addition you can consider `nnz()` function!

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi This question isn't specific to counting the numbers of zeros. It's a more general one.

Comment: I would in any case use `A == 0` because this expression says exactly what you are trying to do, while `~A` relies on the ambiguity of boolean and numerical values, i.e. basically a trick. And as you have found, it is more efficient, too. As to the implementation details, I have no idea, but I generally find that Matlab is efficient enough to allow to what-you-code-is-what-you-mean. (WYCIWYM) ;-)

Comment: Good question! I've always wondered which is faster (also between `logical(A)` and `A~=0`)

Comment: Well. Dunno why it's faster, but it's true.
However, `A` is cached after it is accessed the first time (line 8). so A==0 is faster as A==0 would be without accessing it before.
Trigger `A = round(rand(N_arr(k1))*20);` a second time after the first `clear f` and let's see if it's a big different.
Furthermore, `randi()` would simplify your code.

Comment: @Markus Well I just tried that and the performance plots seem to stay the same. Good suggestion with the `randi`! I might include that.

Answer (score 5):

**This is not strictly an answer but rather my contribution to the discussion**

I used the `profiler` to investigate a slightly-modified version of your code:

```
N_arr = 200:400:3800; %// for medium to large sized input array

for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)

    A = randi(1,N_arr(k1));
    [~]=eq(A,0);
    clear A

    A = randi(1,N_arr(k1));
    [~]=not(A);
    clear A   

end
```

I used the following profiler flags (as per [UndocumentedMatlab's series of posts about `Profiler`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-profiler-options)):

```
profile('-memory','on');
profile('on','-detail','builtin');
```

And here's an excerpt from the profiler results ([link to the larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbufb.png)):
[image: Profiler output]

It seems that the `==` variant allocates a tiny bit of additional memory that allows it to work its magic....

**Regarding your question 2**: Before removing the keeping of `timeall`, I tried plotting the same charts you did in Excel. I didn't observe the behavior you mentioned for `N = 320`. I suspect this may have something to do with the additional wrappers (i.e. function handles) you're using in your code.

---

I thought I'd attach the available documentation for the discussed functions for quick reference.

The documentation for `~` (\MATLAB\R20???\toolbox\matlab\ops\not.m):

```
%~   Logical NOT.
%   ~A performs a logical NOT of input array A, and returns an array
%   containing elements set to either logical 1 (TRUE) or logical 0 (FALSE).
%   An element of the output array is set to 1 if A contains a zero value
%   element at that same array location.  Otherwise, that element is set to
%   0.
%
%   B = NOT(A) is called for the syntax '~A' when A is an object.
%
%   ~ can also be used to ignore input arguments in a function definition,
%   and output arguments in a function call.  See "help punct"

%   Copyright 1984-2005 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

The documentation for `==` (\MATLAB\R20???\toolbox\matlab\ops\eq.m):

```
%==  Equal.
%   A == B does element by element comparisons between A and B
%   and returns a matrix of the same size with elements set to logical 1
%   where the relation is true and elements set to logical 0 where it is
%   not.  A and B must have the same dimensions unless one is a
%   scalar. A scalar can be compared with any size array.
%
%   C = EQ(A,B) is called for the syntax 'A == B' when A or B is an
%   object.

%   Copyright 1984-2005 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

Comment: That peculiar `N = 320` thing could be because of `timeit`. I am looking into `eq` and `not` thing as suggested for the first part. I had similar ideas for it as I was trying out benchmarking between `logical`, `A==0` and `A~=0`, but seems like your ideas would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Also not strictly an answer, but I want to add to the discussion. Maybe it boils down to your function `timeit`.

I've tried Dev-iL's function. I have profiled and got the same results: `EQ` seems to be faster than `NOT` and `EQ` appears to allocate slightly more memory than `NOT`. It seemed logical that if the `EQ` operator is allocating more memory then, as we increased the array size, that memory allocation would also increase. Suspiciously, it does not!

I went on and deleted everything unnecessary and repeated the loop for `N=1000` iterations. The profiler seemed to still agree that `EQ` is faster than `NOT`. But I was not convinced.

Next I did was to remove the weirdly looking `[~] = ~A` and `[~] = A == 0` for something more humane looking like `tmp1 = ~A` and `tmp2 = A == 0` and voilà! The runtimes are almost equal.

[image: profiler results]

So my guess is that you are doing something similar inside your `timeid` function. Worth to note is that the assignment `[~]` slows down both functions, but `NOT` seems to be more affected than `EQ`.

Now the big question: why is the operator `[~]` slowing down the functions? I do not know. Perhaps only Mathworks can answer that. You can open a ticket in the Mathworks webpage.

**Partial answer**: they have almost the same run-time, even for big arrays (biggest array I tried is 10K).

**Unanswered part**: why `[~]` assignment slows down the code. Why `NOT` is more affected than `EQ`.

My Code:

```
clear all
clear classes

array_sizes = [1000:1000:10000];
repetitions = 10000;

for i = 1:length(array_sizes)
    A1 = randi([0, 1], array_sizes(i), 1);
    for j = 1:repetitions
        tmp1 = eq(A1, 0);
    end
end

for i = 1:length(array_sizes)
    A2 = randi([0, 1], array_sizes(i), 1);
    for j = 1:repetitions
        tmp2 = not(A2);
    end
end
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Doing something is faster than doing nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18898698/983722)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I think it's not related. If you remove the lines `tmp1 = eq(A1, 0)` and `tmp2 = not(A2)` and replace them by `eq(A1, 0);` and `not(A2)` you will get the same running time.