# One number array, one logic array. If logic == 1 then use number value, if logic ==0 then return no value

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two matlab arrays, very large, over 41k rows each with 10 columns.

I also have an array of the exact same size filled with 1's and 0's. I need to apply this logic array to the first array and if the value is logic true, pass the number, otherwise if false it must return NaN.

using something like:

```
output= number(array)
```

Only gives an output of the positive logic array values but I need to keep the array the same size/structure, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us generate a dummy matrix and a dummy mask

```
A = rand(5,3);
M = randi([0 1], 5, 3);
```

then you can apply the mask to the original matrix

```
A(not(M)) = nan;
```

Comment: The only issue here is that you lose information from the original `A`. This might be desirable though if memory is running low... Also `not(M)` is normally written as `~M` in Matlab

Comment: [`M==0 might be better than ~M or not(M)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339215/is-a-0-really-better-than-a)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-allocate `output` with `NaN`s:

```
output = NaN(size(number))
output(array) = number(array)
```

Comment: Though not tested, `output(1:size(number,1),1:size(number,2))= NaN` might be better with performance - http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance