# Create a matrix according to a binary matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

Here I got

`A = [1, 2, 3]`

`B = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

I want to create a matrix

`C = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3]`

You can see `B` is like a mask, The number of ones in `B` is equal to the number of elements in `A`. What I want is arrange elements in `A` to the place where `B` is `1`.

Any method without loop?

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but should be close:

```
C = zeros(size(B));
C(logical(B)) = A;
```

This relies on [*logical indexing*](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

Comment: Just wanted to post the same solution, using `C(find(B)) = A;` but this results in the same.

Comment: @Nemesis `logical` is probably faster than `find`

Comment: @LuisMendo Would be interesting to test out whether `==1` is faster than `logical()` though or maybe it's the other way around or maybe it's the same.

Comment: @Divakar a quick test in Octave shows that `== 1` is slightly faster that `logical()`. However, they have different results. A fairer comparison would be against `!= 0` which is still a itsy bitsy quicker.

Comment: @carandraug Since `B = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`, so `B==1` struck me as the first thing, but you are right about `~=0` for a general case. I was able to perform some related tests on these logical array issues and that I think confirm your quick tests too. These are posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339215/is-a-0-really-better-than-a