# Matlab why is logical not of tilde `~` not mentioned docs?

Tags: matlab

I have seen some code that uses:

```
index = findstr('something', 'longer string');
if ~isempty(index)
  % do something
end
```

I looked up [the documentation for MatLab symbols here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsv2dx9-1) and it doesn't mention anything about using `~` for converting primitive integer values into boolean.  i.e. if index is 10 or if it is `[]` then `isempty` will return 0 or 1 which will be converted to 1 or 0 with the `~` operator.  However this use case isn't mentioned in the docs.  Is this a legitimate way of performing negation.  Is there another way of achieving this negation?

Comment: [`Is A==0 really better than ~A?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339215/is-a-0-really-better-than-a) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case *is* mentioned in the docs exactly where your link points to (see "Not Equal To" and "Logical NOT" under "Tilde -- ~"). You can also enter `help ~` in the MATLAB console and get an explanation about usage.

This is *the* legitimate way of performing negation of a boolean. You can apply it to 0 and 1 to flip them, but it will also treat any non-zero value as a 1.

Another way to perform negation of `x` would be `x = 1 - x`, but that only works if `x` is boolean. So for the code you posted, you could do this:

```
index = findstr('something', 'longer string');
if 1 - isempty(index)
  % do something
end
```

Comment: Note that you can also convert to boolean with `logical(10)`, so you could use `1-logical(x)`. But that's basically `~x` anyway.

Comment: I think the original question is sound.  It's not obvious from "To test for inequality values of elements in arrays a and b for inequality, use a~=b"  if the tilde is valid to be used with a primitive integer value and what it would produce.  The "Logical not" part of the documentation linked to similar just talks about arrays: "To find those elements of an array that are zero, use: ~a".  It would be rash to make an assumptions about the return value from an operator on an integer when the only mentioned is of working with arrays.

Comment: Certainly, and of course most other languages use ! instead of ~. Hope my answer doesn't come across as suggesting it is a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

In the workspace, enter

```
doc not
```

or

```
doc ~
```

You will have an answer from the documentation of Matlab.