# Is there a considerable difference between comparing a number to zero with "==" or as a bool?

Tags: python, performance, comparison

Is there a difference, in the way python does the comparing, between:

```
if x == 0.0:
    print "x is zero"
```

and

```
if not x:
    print "x is zero"
```

that would make one preferred to the other?

Comment: `x = False` `if not x. . .`

Comment: If the value will only ever be numeric, then the main difference is readability. `if x == 0.0` makes it clear to a reader that the value is numeric even if they see only that one line; `if not x` does not.

Comment: if there is any chance that `x` will not be a float/int, ie if `x == Null or x == '' or x == []` etc. other than that, as @CharlesDuffy said, its just readability

Comment: @RNar I think you mean `None`, not `Null`

Comment: @Galax yeeeeehhh, thats the one :P

Comment: In MATLAB for an array of numbers, comparing with `0` has slightly upper hand. More info - [`Is A==0 really better than ~A?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339215/is-a-0-really-better-than-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just complementing the comments above, here is the bytecode:

```
In [10]: dis.dis(is_zero_equal_sign)
2         0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
          6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
          9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

3        12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('zero')
         15 PRINT_ITEM          
         16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
         17 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 20)
    >>   20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         23 RETURN_VALUE        

In [11]: dis.dis(is_zero_no_equal_sign)
2         0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
          3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        14

3         6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('zero')
          9 PRINT_ITEM          
         10 PRINT_NEWLINE       
         11 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 14)
    >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         17 RETURN_VALUE
```

Looking at the bytecode it seems like the difference is basically insignificant in terms of performance. When using the equal sign CPython still has to load 0 as a constant and the comparison process is slightly different. If you simply want the one with less steps, you can use the one without '=='.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know bytecode existed, but I guess that is what I wanted to know, which one takes less steps.

Comment: Yeah, you can always check the generated bytecode of a function using the ['dis' module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). ;)