# Create matlab array with same values for several sections

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to create an array of length `Ns(Ns+1)` and I need the first `Ns` elements to be `0`, the next `Ns` elements to be `1`, `...`, the last `Ns` to be `Ns`.

I am well aware that there are plenty of ways to do this with `for-loops`, which I want to avoid for this particular task. I am looking for a way to do this using matlab functions and notions of vectorization.

For example, I had a similar array that I wanted to populate with `0, 1, 2, ..., Ns, 0, 1, 2, ..., Ns, 0, 1, 2, ...` and I accomplished that with

```
my_array = repmat(0:Ns, 1, Ns+1);
```

Is there a similar approach to be taken to achieve my purpose?

One thing I thought I could do would be to create a matrix like

```
0 0 0 ... 0
1 1 1 ... 1
... ... ...
Ns Ns .. Ns
```

and then concatenating the lines; I would know how to create the matrix but not how to concatenate the lines into an array.

Are there any other ways? Suggestions of commands are also acceptable!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* do it with `repmat`, but it's straightforward with [repelem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
my_array = repelem(0:Ns, Ns);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
result = ceil(-1+1/Ns:1/Ns:Ns);
```

Or, for a general array:

```
data = [4 1 2 5];
Ns = 3;
result = data(ceil(1/Ns:1/Ns:numel(data)));
```

which gives

```
result =
     4     4     4     1     1     1     2     2     2     5     5     5
```

This can be done even without `ceil`, exploiting [implicit rounding in colon indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455299/does-matlab-accept-non-integer-indices) (*not documented*; more fun than practical):

```
data = [4 1 2 5];
Ns = 3;
result = data(.5:1/Ns:numel(data)+.5-1/Ns);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) command may be relevant

```
>> Ns = 3;
>> a = repmat(0:Ns, Ns, 1)
a =
 0     1     2     3
 0     1     2     3
 0     1     2     3

>> b = reshape(a, 1, [])
b =
 0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```